# How to show a variable in a url and hide another?

Tags: php

I'm still finding my way around PHP and struggling at the moment with a meta URL.Not sure what I'm missing here so any help would be appreciated.

```
                $make = $_GET['meta_make'];
                $model = $_GET['meta_model'];

                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                if ($make == '' and $model == '') {
                    $term = '';
                    $slug = '';
                    $tax = '';
                    $queryTax = '';
                }elseif ($make != '' and $model == '') {
                    $term = 'terms';
                    $slug = 'id';
                    $tax = 'taxonomy';
                    $queryTax = 'tax_query';
                    $searchTerm = $make&;
                }elseif ($make != '' and $model != '' ){
                    $term = 'terms';
                    $slug = 'field';
                    $tax = 'taxonomy';
                    $queryTax = 'tax_query';
                    $searchTerm = $model;
                }
```

The code above returns the following URL:

```
mysite.com/?meta_make=$make&meta_make=$model
```

Which is fine when both make and model are specified. However, when make is specified but model isn't I need the url to show only make and not model on the URL:

```
mysite.com/?meta_make=$make
```

but instead it shows both and meta_make is empty:

```
mysite.com/?meta_make=$make&meta_make=
```

Comment: Where is the code which actually constructs the URL?

Comment: i would suggest using [http_build_query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php)